# How can I create a drop-down menu which hovers over background image?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, background

I'm new to html/css and i've been working on this drop down menu: http://cssdeck.com/labs/he8ykb8n

**First problem:** I'm trying to make the drop-down menu hover over a background image/slideshow. For some reason i can't do that.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://bildeopplaster.no/3qi so the dropdown menu is hovering over the background image.

**Second problem:** Also if you can see on the demo above you only have "Men's wear" button. I tried to copy the code and just change the button name so all the buttons can be shown like on the nn the picture, but the code didn't align the new button next to the "men's wear" button. Is there any way i can fix so that i can get all the buttons next to each other with same hovering effect?

HTML code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navigation">

<ul>
<li class="menubar"><a href="#">MEN'S WEAR</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">SALE</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="menubar"><a href="#">MEN'S WEAR</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">SALE</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

CSS code for the navigation bar:

```
.navigation {
 position: relative;
background-color: #ddd;
width: 1024px;
height: 42px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}

.navigation a {
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;
}

.menubar ul {
opacity: 0;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;  
}

.menubar {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

.menubar a {
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
top: 12px;
right: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 12px 15px 11px 15px;

 }



.menubar a:nth-child(1) {
color: #000;
list-style: none;
}

.menubar a:hover:nth-child(1) {
color: #fff;
background: #000;

}

.menubar:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;

}

.menubar li{
background: transparent;
}

.dropdown:nth-child(1) {
float: left;
background: #000;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: 22px;
right: 80px;
padding-bottom: 96px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-right: -20px;  
}
.dropdown:nth-child(2) {
float: left;
background: #000;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: 22px;
right: 60px;
padding-bottom: 200px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-right: -20px;  
}

.dropdown:nth-child(3) {
float: left;
background: #000;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: 22px;
right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 200px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-right: -20px;  
}
.dropdown:nth-child(4) {

float: left;
background: #000;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: 22px;
right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 63px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-right: -20px;  
}
.dropdown:nth-child(5) {
float: left;
background: #000;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: 22px;
right: 20px;
left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-left: 42px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 1px;

}


.dropdown a {
right: 10px;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: -40px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #888;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #fff;
}

.dropdown a:nth-child(1) {
color: #cbcbcb;

}

.dropdown ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown ul li {
position: relative;
padding: 8px;
top: 5px;
right: 5px;
font-size: 13.5px;
}

.dropdown ul li a {
font-weight: normal;

}
```

Comment: This is how it looks like when i insert the code above into the main code: http://bildeopplaster.no/3qj if i hover over "men's wear" button the drop-down menu is visible, but the black background as shown on picture is there even if i don't hover over the button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.menubar:hover ul {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

On a side note, always use display:none to hide and display:block to show elements. Visibility can create problems.